# Database of lattices and lattice properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, order-theory, lattice-orders

Are there any websites that are databases of lattices?

I'm also interested in databases distributed as libraries in a programming language or similar.

---

I'm studying a little bit of lattice theory on my own.

I've come across a handful of names of finite lattices such as $N_5$ and $M_4$, shown below:

```
The lattice N_5

       1
     / |
    /  b
   /   |
  c    a
  \   /
    0
```

```
The lattice M_4

    1
 / | | \
 a b c d
 \ | | /
    0
```

I don't know many examples of lattices though, especially weird or poorly behaved ones.

I'm curious, however, whether there are any resources for lattices (especially finite lattices) similar to the following ones:

- Groups [GroupProps](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page)
- Rings [DaRT](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/)
- Topological spaces [Pi-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/)

Comment: There are graphs that have special forms and thus special names (paths, cycles/rings, empties, completes, stars, bi-partites, complete bi-partites, trees, cacti, Cartesian products, ladders, grids/lattices/meshes, et cetera) but I’m not sure if you actually mean that. Also, your $N_5$ happens to be a cycle graph on 5 vertices, and your $M_4$ is $(2,4)$-bipartite complete.

Comment: @Rócherz, I may be misinterpreting your comment, but the diagrams above are [Hasse diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram), not drawings of graphs per se.

Comment: Oh, alright.  Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found https://www.shsu.edu/mem037/Lattices.html and https://b2share.eudat.eu/records/dbb096da4e364b5e9e37b982431f41de, which have good raw data but are not user-friendly like DaRT or π-Base.

The meta-answer: I found these from https://mathdb.mathhub.info/, which is a database of math databases!

Comment: mathdb.mathhub.info is apparently abandoned by the maintainer :(